# How do i get records from table in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I have one table : Questionmaster. it stores DisciplineId,QuestionId,QuestionText etc...

Now My Question is:

I need 10 records of particular DisciplineId, 20 records for another DisciplineId and 30 records for Someother DisciplineId.... What should I do for that? How can I club all statement and get just 60(10+20+30) rows selected?

For one Discipline,it is working as shown below:

```
create or replace function fun_trial(Discipline1,Disc1_NoOfQuestions)
 open cur_out for 
  select getguid() tmp,
  QuestionNo,QuestionText,
  Option1,Option2,
  Option3,Option4,
  Correctanswer,Disciplineid
  from  Questionmaster
  where DisciplineId=discipline1
  AND  rownum <= disc1_NoOfQuestions
   order by tmp ;
return (cur_out);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query uses the analytic function `RANK()` to sort the questions within discipline.  The outer query then selects the first ten, first twenty and first thirty questions for disciplines 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

```
select * from (
  select getguid() tmp
         , QuestionNo
         , QuestionText
         , Option1
         , Option2
         , Option3
         , Option4
         , Correctanswer
         , Disciplineid
         , rank () over (partition by Disciplineid order by QuestionNo ) as rn 
  from  Questionmaster
  where DisciplineId in (1, 2, 3)
)
where ( DisciplineId = 1 and rn <= 10 )
or    ( DisciplineId = 2 and rn <= 20 )
or    ( DisciplineId = 3 and rn <= 30 )
/
```

Comment: @APC: Nitpick, didn't you mean dense_rank() ?  (For unlikely cases of equal values of QuestionNo) :-)

Comment: @khb - actually if that were a possibility I would choose `row_number()`, as I think it is key to the solution that we return exactly *10* questions for discipline #1, *20* questions for discipline #2, etc.